# How to chunk items from pipeline in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

in my PowerShell cmdlet I get an arbitrary number of items via pipeline and want to return chunks of a specified number of items.

When, for example, my script gets as input:

```
("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
```

And I define, let's say 4 as chunk size, I'd like to return something like this:

```
(
    ("A", "B", "C", "D"),
    ("E", "F", "G")
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that integrating this functionality into `Select-Object` with a `-ReadCount` parameter in the future is the subject of [GitHub proposal #8270](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8270).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a simple function that buffers N input objects before spitting out a new array, then output any buffered values you might have left over when you reach the end of the input sequence:

```
function chunk {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [psobject]$InputObject,

    [ValidateRange(1, 100000)]
    [int]$ChunkSize = 4
  )

  begin {
    $counter = 0
    # Set up array that will act as buffer
    $chunk = [object[]]::new($ChunkSize)
  }

  process {
    # Add input object to next available slot in array
    $chunk[$counter++] = $InputObject

    if($counter -eq $ChunkSize){
        # If we've filled the buffer, output it as a new chunk
      Write-Output $chunk -NoEnumerate

      # Reset counter and buffer
      $counter = 0
      $chunk = [object[]]::new($ChunkSize)
    }
  }

  end {
    if($counter){
      # There's no more input but we have some data left over still, output it 
      Write-Output $chunk[0..($counter-1)] -NoEnumerate
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
PS ~> $firstChunk,$nextChunk = "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" |chunk
PS ~> $firstChunk
A
B
C
D
PS ~> $nextChunk
E
F
G
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it worked well. I tried something quite similar, but somehow it didn't work as expected. Apparently "-NoEnumerate" did the trick, which I didn't know before.

Comment: @KaiRadewald That's right, `-NoEnumerate` signals that "the downstream consumer should not enumerate this enumerable", means you can pipe the resulting chunks to another cmdlet: `1..100 |chunk -ChunkSize 15 |ForEach-Object { '[{0}]' -f ($_ -join ', ')}`

Comment: Eh, that's NOT a summary of our chat @mklement0, that's a summary of your position/understanding of the issue :) Commands don't enumerate output, they leave that to the pipeline processor. Saying the output-producing command does it is just as irresponsible as my claim that the consumer does it.

Comment: I'm reposting my summary with different framing to avoid the impression
that it represents a _consensus_ reached in [our chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243620/room-for-mklement0-and-mathias-r-jessen).
While some common ground was reached, there is still a fundamental disconnect. I'm posting the summary in response to your initial comment,
which I think is misleading. I think your characterization of this summary is incorrect.
I've added clarifications to the chat, which may be of interest to
future readers (I understand that you don't want to continue the discussion).

Comment: Note that `-NoEnumerate` signals nothing to the downstream consumer (though that consumer is affected by it). Commands (implicitly or explicitly) write to the success output stream / pipeline. (In PowerShell code) enumerables are by default _enumerated_ when they are written: that is, instead of writing the enumerable itself, its _elements_ are written, _one by one_. `Write-Output -NoEnumerate` modifies this behavior to instead write a given enumerable itself, _as a single object_. All this happens when the objects are written, irrespective of who consumes the output.

Comment: love it's simplicity

Answer (score 1):

As of powershell 7 and if you have .net 6 installed:

```
$arr = [string[]]@("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
$chunks = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Chunk($arr, 4)
```

May be used like so:

```
foreach ($chunk in $chunks) {
 "hello " + $chunk
}
```

Which outputs as:

```
hello A B C D
hello E F G
```

The Chunk function takes any IEnumerable as its first argument.

EDIT: Meh had to do this with powershell 5 :(

So for powershell 5, the accepted answer is good, but if you want a type safe approach:

```
function chunk {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [System.Collections.IEnumerable]$Iter,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][ValidateRange([uint32]::MinValue, [uint32]::MaxValue)]
    [uint32]$ChunkSize
  )
  $type = $iter[0].GetType().Name
  $numer = $Iter.GetEnumerator()
  $chunks = new-object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.collections.Generic.List[$($type)]]
  while ($numer.MoveNext()) {
    $i = 1
    $chunk = new-object System.collections.Generic.List[$($type)]
    $chunk.Add($numer.Current)
    while ($i % $ChunkSize -gt 0 -and $numer.MoveNext()) {
      $i++
      $chunk.Add($numer.Current)
    }
    $chunks.Add($chunk)
  }
  return , $chunks
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I could save it to a file first, it could work using get-content's -readcount parameter.  I couldn't keep the 2 lists wrapped with regular arrays and +=, so I used an arraylist, hiding the output of arraylist.add().  I wish you could do named pipes on the fly like in zsh.

```
echo A B C D E F G | set-content file    # PS7:  'A'..'G'
get-content file -ReadCount 4 | 
  % { [collections.arraylist]$list = @() } { $list.add($_) > $null }


$list[0]

A
B
C
D


$list[1]

E
F
G
```