# How do i split big array in smaller array then use smaller array in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have big list of servers . Around 700 servers. I want to split this big list to smaller list (around 30 servers ) then use smaller list do more tasks later part of script. Having hard time creating smaller list which i can call later part of script.

```
#Create server list from Mass server list
$batchsize = 30
$set = 1
$serverarry = @()
foreach ($server in gc ./servers.txt){
      
      $serverarry += $server
                       if ($serverarry.count -eq $batchsize){
                          $'array+$set' = @()
                          $'array+$set' = $serverarry
                          $set +=1
                                                     }


                                       }
$array1
$array2
$array3
###############end of creating list #########
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71749556/how-to-chunk-items-from-pipeline-in-powershell

Comment: You can use the `-ReadCount` parameter which works like `-OutBuffer` to send them in *chunks* of 30. Then, you can create an array and name it dynamically using `Set-Variable`